# Is there a way to recover a Google Account with just the User Name and Password?

Tags: account-management, google-account

I created a new Google account to use YouTube with a while back. Thing is, whilst I remember the Username I used and the password, I cannot actually remember the email address I used.

Is there a way to recover the email address for a Google Account using the Username and password?

Comment: Have you tried logging in your good account using your username?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the User-name and password, then you can just log in without having to do any password recovery.

And once you have logged in, you can go into the settings and see what primary email address is associated with the account.   And you can change it - provided it's not a gmail address  (but it it is a gmail address, then your user-name will be the same as the email address).

Comment: Thanks but that doesnt seem to be working. I cannot put in my name eg: "John Smith" and password. It still asks for an email address

Comment: "John Smith" is not a Google account name.   All Google account names have the form of email addresses - even though the primary email address that is associated with the account is not the same as the email address that is the account name.

Comment: You could try using Google's account recovery tool (google it) - but you will need to remember some more details about the account.